# First item from a Map on JavaScript ES2015

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ecmascript-6

I have a `Map` like this:

```
const m = new Map();
m.set('key1', {})
.
m.set('keyN' {})
```

the `Map`can have 1 or many items. Can I get the first item by index, without `m.get('key1')` and without a iterator loop?

like: `m.get()[0]`

Comment: @Andrey from Mozilla MDN: "A Map iterates its elements in insertion order, whereas iteration order is not specified for Objects." https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Use the [`Map.prototype.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries#Using_entries()) function, like this

```js
const m = new Map();
m.set('key1', {})
m.set('keyN', {})

console.log(m.entries().next().value); // [ 'key1', {} ]
```

---

If you want to get the first key, then use [`Map.prototype.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys), like this

```
console.log(m.keys().next().value); // key1
```

---

Similarly if you want to get the first value, then you can use [`Map.prototype.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values), like this

```
console.log(m.values().next().value); // {}
```

---

The reason why we have to call `next()` on the returned values is that, all those functions return [iterators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Iterators). Read more about the iteration protocol [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols).

Comment: Any reason you changed the `'keyN'` keys the OP used?

Comment: what about the last key/value?

Comment: Is it possible to replace the first entry with another? Like in above example can I *replace* (not add) the entry `key1 : {}` with `key3: { val: 3}`, without creating a new Map?

Answer (score 26):

For the specific example you are wondering about, destructuring would be perfect.

```
let m = new Map();
m.set('key1', {});
m.set('key2', {});

let [[, obj]] = m;
```

e.g.

```
let [pair] = m;
let [key, obj] = pair;
```

is one option to destructure and then grab the value, but the easier option would be

```
let [obj] = m.values();
```

Answer (score 12):

It could also be done using the spread feature at ES6 and the next versions. Let's declare a new Map variable, then add two values.
After that, we will use `...` to convert the map into array or you can use `Array.from` then to get the first element just use `[0]` on the gotten array.

```js
const m = new Map();
m.set('key1', 1);
m.set('key2', 2);

console.log([...m][0]);    // ['key1', 1]
```

Or quickly by using distruct feature for javascript array, so that `[k, v]` array refers to first item at the map.

```js
const [[k, v]] = m;
console.log(k, v); // 'key1', 1
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!

Comment: You are converting it to an array then showing first element

Answer (score 9):

Also, that is correct for both `Set` and `Map`: you can convert anything to `Array` and then get any element by its index. Something like this:

```js
const m = new Map();
m.set('key1', {});
m.set('key2', {});

console.log(Array.from(m)[0]); // ['key1', {}]
```

Comment: This version is too much expensive since it creates a new array from the map.

Answer (score 3):

For all iterable objects you can use the iterator [object[Symbol.iterator]()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/@@iterator).

In our case this will point to the `entries()` method as explained in the above MDN page :

> The map iterator function, which is the entries() function by default.

```js
const m = new Map();
m.set('key1', {})
m.set('keyN', {})

console.log(m[Symbol.iterator]().next().value); // [ 'key1', {} ]
```

And here is a benchmark of all solutions :
https://jsbench.me/9fkpm6q9y0/1

The `entries()` version wins but it is very tight to the iterator version. This is logical since `[Symbol.iterator]()` calls `entries()`.

Comment: I think `.entries().next().value` is easier to read than using `Symbol.iterator` but I upvoted you for actually benchmarking the solution. One thing I noticed: `let [pair] = map;` is only 16% slower than `entries`/`iterator` while `let [[key, val]] = map;` is 33% slower -- it must take time to allocate that extra "double-destructured" anonymous array.