# Get the first property of an ES6 class using Symbol.iterator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So I have a class similar to this:

```
class List {
  constructor() {
    this._rows = [];
  }

  add(row) {
    this._rows.push(row);
  }

  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return this._rows.values();
  }
}
```

I know in order to get the first element I could access it via

```
List._rows[0]
```

as well as

```
for (var row of List) {
  break;
}
```

I'm more curious as I'm trying to treat this._rows as private, and I'd prefer to not have a loop just to get the first index.  Is there any other way?

Comment: Are you open to adding something like a `first` property to your `List` class?

Comment: How would you like to access it?

Comment: see also [First item from a Map on Javascipt ES2015](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32373301/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get iterator of your object and access values with `next` method:

```
let list = new List();
let iterator = list[Symbol.iterator]();
iterator.next().value; // first item
iterator.next().value; // second item
```

So that shorthand to get first value is:

```
list[Symbol.iterator]().next().value;
```

In real code do not forget to check if iterator has next value what indicates the `done` property of item returned by iterator.