# How to fetch first value from a map in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I have a map in react with key and value both as string,like below:

```
let map=new Map();
map.set("foo","bar");
map.set("foo-bar","bar-foo");
```

How can i fetch the first value from this map ?

Comment: `map.get("foo")`?

Comment: `map.values()[0]`?

Comment: key has not been given,without using key

Comment: Does this answer your question? [First item from a Map on JavaScript ES2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32373301/first-item-from-a-map-on-javascript-es2015)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` built in `keys()` method that returns an iterator.
Then you can call `.next()` on the iterator to fetch the first item.

The item is an object, so you will need to use the property `value`.

```js
let map=new Map();
map.set("foo","bar");
map.set("foo-bar","bar-foo");

const keysIterator = map.keys();
const firstKeyObject = keysIterator.next();
const firstKey = firstKeyObject.value;

console.log(map.get(firstKey));


// or simply:
console.log(map.get( map.keys().next().value ));
```

Comment: Why not just `map.values().next().value`?

Comment: @Cully I deliberately split the code into multiple lines to make it clear what the code does.

Comment: Yeah, but why get the value indirectly using the key? You could just get the values and then get the first value.