# How to replace first element in Map?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a Map:

```
private objects =  new Map<DrawingObject, Polygon[]>();
```

I want to replace only first element in map, not touching others. How to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [First item from a Map on JavaScript ES2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32373301/first-item-from-a-map-on-javascript-es2015)

Comment: You'll probably have to loop over the keys and then delete the first one?

Comment: I dont need delete, I need replace

Comment: Then use set instead of delete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
objects.keys().next().value
```

to get the first key in a map.

So to set the first value, use the `Map.prototype.set();` method using `objects.keys().next().value` as the key.

```
objects.set(objects.keys().next().value, 'new value');
```